# I wanna replace the % mark to - this mark of url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanna replace the % mark to - this mark of url

from

> `http://localhost/news/news/6/1/my%news%of%bangla
>   to
>
> http://localhost/news/news/6/1/my-news-of-bangla

Comment: `str_replace("%", "-", $string);`

Comment: `$string = "http://localhost/news/news/6/1/my%news%of%bangla"; 
$string = str_replace("%", "-", $string);
echo $string;`

Comment: Thanks bro i just forget about this method..

Answer (score 1):

let you have an  tag

```
$pageName = "my news of bangla"; 
$pageUrl = str_replace("%", "-", $pageName); 

<a href="example.com/<?php echo $pageUrl; ?>"> my news of bangla </a>
```

Then use like